Django template not loading correctly
In my django project i am using a template named main.html in this html file i am importing all the required css and js files i will share the structure below
{% load static %}
    <!-- site Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'img/favicon/favicon.png' %}" sizes="32x32">

    <!-- css Icon Font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/vendor/gicons.css' %}">

    <!-- Tailwindcss -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/plugins/tailwindcss3.4.1' %}"></script>

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

<script src="{% static 'js/plugins/jquery-3.7.1.min.js ' %}"></script>

and i am extending this template to product-details.html file like below
{% extends 'index/main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

content of the product-details.html

{% endblock %}

now the problem is css of this product-details.html is not loading correctly and i am using tailwind as a framework
is my way of extending template correct?
I tried to load the page but css not loading properly

Please ensure that the following steps are completed.:

Ensure the Tailwind css path correct on main.html

if you are using tailwind, tailwind.config.js file correctly to include the paths of your templates

Check your white space in static file path

Ensure Static File configuration on settings
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  STATICFILES_DIRS = [
      BASE_DIR / "static",
   ]


Clear Cache on Browser and rerun the project



I guess the problem in your settings.py
make sure you joined the folder where your template is located in your setings.py
for an example
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'the folder where your template is located')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'core.context_processor.default',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

also make sure you put the folder name properly the folder where ur template is located in here

All my HTML templates are in the "templates" folder and I added this to in settings.py and all my js, and CSS are in my static folder

share your settings.py

TEMPLATES = [     {         'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',         'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],         'APP_DIRS': True,         'OPTIONS': {             'context_processors': [                 'django.template.context_processors.debug',                 'django.template.context_processors.request',                 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',                 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',                 'django.template.context_processors.request',             ],         },     }, ]

ok you can add the css file link in your product-details.htm and tell me what is the result
